# Lines are changed in android xml file in Eclipse

Tags: mouse, eclipse, android

I am using android sdk in eclipse IDE.

Here i am facing very critical problem in `Eclipse IDE.`

When i open any `android layout XML file` and try to change anything manually where android layout xml file is written. that time i have to click on any line to get cursor on that line so i used mouse click event or laptop touch pad click but sometimes lines are changed due to these type of click. problem is like that lines are disappear and when i click again at somewhere else then other different lines appears.

Here file content not changed really but its appear and disappear when i clicked on any line of android XML file.

I also updated my `SDK` tools and `ADT` and my eclipse also.

I also changed my eclipse with two and theree version but problem is remains same.

Please Solve my this problem without this i cant do anything in Android GUI related programing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463401/adt-eclipse-graphics-display-artifacts-and-moving-lines-of-text-in-main-xml

Basically, turn off "Automatically format the XML edited by the visual layout editor" (in Preferences | Android | Editors).